# Does JMSPaymentPaypalBundle support chained payments?

Tags: symfony, paypal, chained-payments, jmspaymentpaypalbundle

I need to implement chained payments in my application and I am using Symfony.

I found JMSPaymentPaypalBundle to be recommended for payments but would like to know if it support chained payments before I dive in.

The are lots of examples how to use standard payments methods but could not find anything about support for adaptive payments.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this one , I have already integrate paypal adaptive payments with this.

"paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php": "dev-master",

```
        $receiverList = new \ReceiverList($receiver);
        $baseUrl = $this->generateUrl('sylius_homepage', array(), true);
        $payRequest = new \PayRequest(new \RequestEnvelope("en_US"), "PAY",
        $baseUrl, $offer->getProduct()->getCurrencyCode(), $receiverList,        
        $baseUrl."payment/success_payment");
        $payRequest->feesPayer = "EACHRECEIVER";
        $payRequest->memo = "DeepClass";    

        $payRequest->reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError  = "false";
        //$payRequest->senderEmail = "milosmilojevicfacebook@gmail.com";

        $service = new \AdaptivePaymentsService();

        try {
        /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
        $response = $service->Pay($payRequest);
        //var_dump($response);
        $link = PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL . '_ap-payment&paykey=' . $response->payKey;
```

Comment: I know how to use adaptive sdk itself, the question was about its integration with JMSPaymentPaypalBundle.